# Using the Template Design Pattern to reduce code duplication between two algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, template

I have made a Skyline query solver which for now can solve the query with two different algorithms.

The first is Block-nested loop (BNL) and the second is Sort filter skyline (SFS). The two are extremely similar. I will explain the basic things that are needed to review the part I am interested in so I won't bore you with the whole algorithm.

> **BNL** and **SFS** have two parts, divide and merge. Divide is exactly the same and merge is mostly the same with two main
>   differences:
>
> 1. SFS sorts the key-value RDD input by values while BNL does not.
> 2. SFS does not discard `Point2DAdvanced` elements from the `globalSkylines` list (because it is not needed since the
>      `Point2DAdvanced` are sorted) but BNL does.
>
> In order to differentiate these main differences I thought that the
>   *Template Method Pattern* was my best bet with two hook functions:
>
> 1. 'sortRDD` in SFS sorts the key-value RDD by value and returns it while in BNL it just returns the same RDD.
> 2. `globalAddDiscardOrDominate` in SFS just checks if the `candidateSkyline` is dominated by any other skyline points and if it
>      is then it is discarded, otherwise it is added to the list. In BNL it
>      also checks if the `candidateSkyline` dominates any point in the list
>      in order to remove it.

These are the main differences that I have based my template method pattern on. Here are the classes themselves:

**`BlockNestedLoopTemplate` class:**

```
public abstract class BlockNestedLoopTemplate implements SkylineAlgorithm, Serializable {

    private final transient TextFileToPointRDD txtToPoints;
    private FlagPointPairProducer flagPointPairProducer;

    public BlockNestedLoopTemplate(SparkContextWrapper sparkContext) {
        this.txtToPoints = new TextFileToPointRDD(sparkContext);
    }

    @Override
    public final List<Point2DAdvanced> getSkylinePoints(String filePath) {
        JavaRDD<Point2DAdvanced> points = txtToPoints.getPointRDDFromTextFile(filePath, " ");
        flagPointPairProducer = createFlagPointPairProducer(points);

        JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Iterable<Point2DAdvanced>> localSkylinePointsByFlag = divide(points);
        JavaRDD<Point2DAdvanced> skylinePoints = merge(localSkylinePointsByFlag);

        return skylinePoints.collect();
    }

    private FlagPointPairProducer createFlagPointPairProducer(JavaRDD<Point2DAdvanced> points) {
        Point2DAdvanced medianPoint = MedianPointFinder.findMedianPoint(points);
        return new FlagPointPairProducer(medianPoint);
    }

    private JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Iterable<Point2DAdvanced>> divide(JavaRDD<Point2DAdvanced> points) {
        JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> flagPointPairs = points.mapToPair(p -> flagPointPairProducer.getFlagPointPair(p));
        JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Iterable<Point2DAdvanced>> pointsGroupedByFlag = flagPointPairs.groupByKey();
        JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Iterable<Point2DAdvanced>> flagsWithLocalSkylines
                = pointsGroupedByFlag.mapToPair(fp -> new Tuple2(fp._1, getLocalSkylinesWithBNL(fp._2)));

        return flagsWithLocalSkylines;
    }

    private Iterable<Point2DAdvanced> getLocalSkylinesWithBNL(Iterable<Point2DAdvanced> pointIterable) {
        List<Point2DAdvanced> localSkylines = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Point2DAdvanced point : pointIterable) {
            localAddDiscardOrDominate(localSkylines, point);
        }
        return localSkylines;
    }

    private void localAddDiscardOrDominate(List<Point2DAdvanced> localSkylines, Point2DAdvanced candidateSkylinePoint) {
        for (Iterator it = localSkylines.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Point2DAdvanced pointToCheckAgainst = (Point2DAdvanced) it.next();
            if (pointToCheckAgainst.dominates(candidateSkylinePoint)) {
                return;
            } else if (candidateSkylinePoint.dominates(pointToCheckAgainst)) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
        localSkylines.add(candidateSkylinePoint);
    }

    protected JavaRDD<Point2DAdvanced> merge(
            JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Iterable<Point2DAdvanced>> localSkylinesGroupedByFlag) {

        JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> ungroupedLocalSkylines
                = localSkylinesGroupedByFlag.flatMapValues(point -> point);
        JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> sortedLocalSkylines = sortRDD(ungroupedLocalSkylines);

        JavaRDD<List<Tuple2<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced>>> groupedByTheSameId = groupByTheSameId(sortedLocalSkylines);
        JavaRDD<Point2DAdvanced> globalSkylinePoints
                = groupedByTheSameId.flatMap(singleList -> getGlobalSkylineWithBNLAndPrecomparisson(singleList));

        return globalSkylinePoints;
    }

    protected abstract JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> sortRDD(JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> flagPointPairs);

    private JavaRDD<List<Tuple2<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced>>> groupByTheSameId(JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> ungroupedLocalSkylines) {
        JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> mergedInOnePartition = ungroupedLocalSkylines.coalesce(1);
        JavaRDD<List<Tuple2<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced>>> groupedByTheSameId = mergedInOnePartition.glom();
        return groupedByTheSameId;
    }

    private List<Point2DAdvanced> getGlobalSkylineWithBNLAndPrecomparisson(List<Tuple2<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced>> flagPointPairs) {
        List<Point2DAdvanced> globalSkylines = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Tuple2<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> flagPointPair : flagPointPairs) {
            PointFlag flag = flagPointPair._1;
            if (!passesPreComparisson(flag)) {
                continue;
            }

            Point2DAdvanced point = flagPointPair._2;
            globalAddDiscardOrDominate(globalSkylines, point);
        }
        return globalSkylines;
    }

    private boolean passesPreComparisson(PointFlag flagToCheck) {
        PointFlag rejectedFlag = new PointFlag(1, 1);
        return !flagToCheck.equals(rejectedFlag);
    }

    protected abstract void globalAddDiscardOrDominate(
            List<Point2DAdvanced> globalSkylines, Point2DAdvanced candidateGlobalSkylinePoint);
}
```

**`BlockNestedLoop` (BNL) extension:**

```
public class BlockNestedLoop extends BlockNestedLoopTemplate {

    public BlockNestedLoop(SparkContextWrapper sparkContext) {
        super(sparkContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> sortRDD(JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> flagPointPairs) {
        return flagPointPairs;
    }

    @Override
    protected void globalAddDiscardOrDominate(List<Point2DAdvanced> globalSkylines, Point2DAdvanced candidateGlobalSkylinePoint) {
        for (Iterator it = globalSkylines.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Point2DAdvanced skyline = (Point2DAdvanced) it.next();
            if (skyline.dominates(candidateGlobalSkylinePoint)) {
                return;
            } else if (candidateGlobalSkylinePoint.dominates(skyline)) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
        globalSkylines.add(candidateGlobalSkylinePoint);
    }
}
```

**`SortFilterSkyline` (SFL) extension:**

```
public class SortFilterSkyline extends BlockNestedLoopTemplate {

    public SortFilterSkyline(SparkContextWrapper sparkContext) {
        super(sparkContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> sortRDD(
            JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> flagPointPairs) {

        JavaPairRDD<Point2DAdvanced, PointFlag> swapped = flagPointPairs.mapToPair(fp -> fp.swap());
        JavaPairRDD<Point2DAdvanced, PointFlag> sorted = swapped.sortByKey(new DominationComparator());
        JavaPairRDD<PointFlag, Point2DAdvanced> unswapped = sorted.mapToPair(fp -> fp.swap());
        return unswapped;
    }

    @Override
    protected void globalAddDiscardOrDominate(
            List<Point2DAdvanced> globalSkylines, Point2DAdvanced candidateGlobalSkylinePoint) {

        if (!isDominatedBySkylines(globalSkylines, candidateGlobalSkylinePoint)) {
            globalSkylines.add(candidateGlobalSkylinePoint);
        }
    }

    private boolean isDominatedBySkylines(List<Point2DAdvanced> skylines, Point2DAdvanced candidateSkylinePoint) {
        for (Point2DAdvanced skyline : skylines) {
            if (skyline.dominates(candidateSkylinePoint)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I mainly care about is if there is a better way to reduce the code duplication. As a secondary issue feel free to comment on anything code wise (naming conventions, method sorting or anything that you feel is worth changing).